# Switches and routers interfaces name dictionary

Tags: networking, router, switching, network-interface

I am curently looking for a dictionary that contains all (or a lot) of interfaces names for routers and switches.
For instance a dictionary that would look like this :

[[Cisco : GigabithEthernet1/0/0, ..., GigabithEthernet1/0/28, FastEthernet1/0/0, ...],
[Juniper : ge-0/0/1, ..., ge-0/0/12,fa-0/0/1, ...,fa-0/0/12]]

I would like it to contain as much of interfaces names of as much of brand as possible.

I have already been looking for it for a long time now, but I have not been able to find anything so far. So if anyone has something to share on this it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The interfaces names you shared are depending on configuration on the nodes. So that you need to create it individually. To create this type of dictionary, you can use python netmiko/paramiko library to connect device through SSH. You need to send correct commends to get interfaces information for each vendor. Then, you can manipulate your data and then create a dictionary files for each vendor.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 0):

A quick update to inform you that I have not been able to find a dictionnary and that after some research I find out that you don't need one if your problem is to identify interfaces on a switch or router.
Using SNMP, you can find which one of the interfaces on your machine is a physical or logical interface. So I used this reference to know which one of my interfaces are physical interfaces or not.
The OID is : 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3

Thanks for the help I have been given so far !